# mysql use UNION between preparred statement result and called stored procedure result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Example working query inside one stored procedure that working good:

```
SET @vs_query = "
    (SELECT text_page FROM pages 
    WHERE lang = ? AND (
        alias_page = 'general_structure' OR alias_page = 'header' 
        OR alias_page = 'footer'
    ) LIMIT 3)

    UNION

    (SELECT text_page FROM pages 
    WHERE lang = ? AND page_name = ? LIMIT 1 );
";

PREPARE stmt FROM @vs_query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @user_language,@user_language, @requested_page;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

What I looking for is if is possible to use some like this instead:
(That I have tried and got sintax error but is only for example)

```
SET @vs_query = "

    /*there the ? is @user_language var */
    (CALL get_structure(?))

    UNION

    (SELECT text_page FROM pages 
    WHERE lang = ? AND page_name = ? LIMIT 1 );
";
```

What I try to do is to put the first query in one stored procedure (because I need to call it in more places of mi code) and use the returned recordset in a UNION

It exist a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. I'd recommend one of possible solutions - using temporary table for this union, which must be truncated and filled in your stored procedure. Just call it before.